# Deploying Python function that uses multiple python files

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I think I'm trying to do something really simple but keep running into problems.

I am trying to deploy a Python function that uses two Python files, `__init__.py` and another one called `handler.py`. Here is all of `__init__.py`:

```
import json
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import handler

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    result = handler.yourFunction(req.params, None)
    return func.HttpResponse(result)
```

For whatever reason, whenever I run this function I get an error saying that the handler module cannot be found. I can view the folder structure on Azure and see that it is in the same folder as `__init__.py`.

I am really confused why this is not working. I can deploy Node.js functions just fine but Python ones just keep running into problems.

Comment: What exactly is the traceback on the import?

Comment: Here is another import statement:

Result: Failure
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Inspector'
Stack:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 239, in _handle__function_load_request
    func_request.metadata.entry_point)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 66, in load_function
   ...
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/pythontestt51234y/handler.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Inspector import *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supporting python very well using Azue function service.

For the python module finding mechanism, it will find the module listed in `sys.path`. So if you want to import your own module. You need to add your current folder in `sys.path`. Add something like this before import your own module:

```python
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))))

import handler
```

This works on my local.

Comment: Awesome! Solved my issue. I spent DAYS trying to figure out why this was not working.

Comment: So I have __init__.py and blob-quickstart-v12.py within the same Azure Function "Test-v3". While __init__.py is a blob trigger, "blob-quickstart-v12.py " has the python code that I want to run. Can you please exemplify how I should be running this? I am new to Azure function

Answer (score 2):

I found this worked fine:

```
from . import mylibrary as mlib
```

This also helped in places:

```
from . import mylibrary # pylint: disable=relative-beyond-top-level
from ..myfolder import mylibrary # pylint: disable=relative-beyond-top-level
```

Disabling the pylint warning here as it's a false positive for azure.

Answer (score 1):

This document goes into some patterns you can use to import shared code:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#folder-structure

I personally have found luck with `import ..SharedCode/myHander`